# Retrieve HostCallbackInfo from AudioKit to Sync IAA and AKSequencer

Tags: audiounit, audiokit, aksequencer

I'm struggled trying to sync AKSequencer with IAA.
Need to get HostCallbackInfo from the AudioUnit. In Core Audio and ObjC, would be something like this:

```
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(HostCallbackInfo);
callBackInfo = (HostCallbackInfo*) malloc(dataSize);
OSStatus result = AudioUnitGetProperty(audioController.audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_HostCallbacks, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, callBackInfo, &dataSize);
```

Now, with AudioKit and AKSequencer in Swift, how can I get this HostCallbackInfo data ?